# Программа не заменяет русские символы

Tags: c++, строки

Задание: Замените все заглавные буквы на «-», а строчные на «*»

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath> 
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cwctype>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif



void init_locale()
{
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1200");
    (void)_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    (void)_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
#else
    locale::global(locale(""));
    wcout.imbue(locale());
    //wcin.imbue( locale() );
#endif
}



int main()
{
    init_locale();

    wstring str;
    getline(wcin, str);
    size_t n = str.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) str[i] = '-'; //A-Z
        if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) str[i] = '*'; //a-z
        if (str[i] >= 128 && str[i] <= 159) str[i] = '-'; //А-Я
        if (str[i] == 240) str[i] = '-'; //Ё
        if (str[i] == 241) str[i] = '*'; //ё
        if (str[i] >= 160 && str[i] <= 175) str[i] = '*'; //а-п
        if (str[i] >= 224 && str[i] <= 239) str[i] = '*'; //р-я
    }
    wcout << L"Результат:";
    wcout << str;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1200"); это что за кодировка?

Comment: Вместо (неправильных) волшебных чисел следует сравнивать с символами `if (L'Ё' == str[i])`

Comment: @user7860670 Вообще-то в разных кодировках представление символов разное. И есть возможность что реализация поддерживает unicode, и тогда все что не латынь - больше одного байта. Тут уже библиотеку работы со строками надо использовать.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie ¿А для чего там в начале `L` по-вашему?

Comment: @user7860670  а так вы полагаетесь на то что текст программы и окружение котором она работает - в одной кодировке. А проверки больше меньше все равно не помогут - порядок зависит от кодировок.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Было бы удивительно, если бы программа для windows, работающая с wchar_t оказалась в окружении какой-то необычной кодировки.

Comment: @user7860670 Отнюдь. Это как раз вечный анекдот у меня на работе. Даже при использовании Qt - проблемы. Консоль и  GUI работают по разному и в разных кодировках. Настройки ОС изменямы. Еще целый ворох проблем с версией ОС и версией run-time.  Ряд комбинаций компилятора и ОС в принципе нельзя заставить работать с русским языком вот так напрямую. А уж редактор  может по умолчанию использовать UTF-8 а не wchar-овские 1251  и пр.  Кто-то пользуется студией, у кого-то Creator

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie *"wchar-овские 1251"* - ну тогда не удивительно, что у вас там анекдот на работе... Во-первых однобайтовая кодировка 1251 не имеет отношения к wchar, во-вторых кодировка редактора при использовании wchar роли тоже не играет (исходники в utf8 - вполне себе стандарт), далее QT действительно проблемы и настройки консоли ОС можно подкручивать, однако режим работы с wchar доступен всегда, так как это нативный режим консоли, да и WinAPI в целом.